# Body width doesn't change

Tags: html, css

I'm making a fixed width (120px) website for old feature phones that **don't** respond to media queries. The width of the body won't change even when I've defined it as 120px. When I open the website on the phone, it shows a huge horizontal scroll bar showing me a lot of blank space on the right which I'm assuming is the body. In the screen shot attached, I've set background color of body to red so you can see the problem (I also had to blackout the content for client privacy).
I'm using the following code:

```
html {

width:120x;
margin-left:0px;

}

body{
    width:120px;
    font-family: arial;
    font: arial;
    margin-left: 0px;
    max-width:120px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: what element is the `background-color` on? One of the elements must be overflowing. Try adding overflow hidden to the body if you want to hide it.

Comment: I suggest you to use width:100% instead of 120px, so it at leasts makes use of the full width :-). Also what Guy posted, something must probably be wider than the body try adding a border to everything if it's hard to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use un child  to wrap your content with a max-width.

and  tags don't allow to do what you want.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    Your content goes here
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #d63b24;
    color: #fff;
}
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/vinzcelavi/1rx7yn57/

Answer (score 2):

I think you've a typo here:

```
html {

width:120x;
margin-left:0px;

}
```

The width should be 120px

Answer (score 1):

Remove the typo:

```
html {
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body {
    min-width: 1024px;
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/enxRw/1/